# Creating an .ovf virtual machine on the command line

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, installer-anaconda

Instead of an .iso image, I am to create an .ovf file for a Linux distributions, at first a Fedora.

The goal is that my students could use a Linux distribution at ease with Virtualbox, without a need to actually install it but only to import the .ovf image. The goal is not to have a professional distribution but to have a small barrier to use Linux on their Windows machines.

What do I need for this in VirtualBox? I would like to do this as a script, not as installing a Linux by hand and then exporting the .ovf image.

Can I make a fully automatic script that takes an .iso image of a Fedora release, installs it through some automatic configuration script (anaconda?) and then creates an .ovf file?

Comment: You may try Parker https://github.com/hashicorp/packer & doc here https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html , a tool to make headless installation of iso to generate multiple types of VM archives.

Comment: @user.dz Could you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [HashiCorp / Packer](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer)

[Packer](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer) is a tool to make headless installation of CD/DVD ISO images to generate multiple types of virtual-machine/cloud image/archives.

1. Create you build template (JSON format), example `my-template.json`
2. `packer verify my-template.json`
3. `packer build my-template.json`

Many distributions like Ubuntu/Fedora require also unattended install configuration same format usually used for net-install. Look for `preseed` and `kickstart`.

For your case, [`virtualbox-iso`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html) is the convenient builder. There are many other builders, check that documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you configure Fedora using VB and then export as an OVF.

1. Change background to school wallpaper
2. Install favorites apps
3. Enable repositories, update distro
4. Create add new user script on login

Then all the students have to do is import OVF to Virtualbox. I haven't used this version in a while but to speed things up you can use Portable Virtualbox

https://www.vbox.me/

Just a note to consider. Ubuntu ISO can run LIVE and persistent so the students would just boot directly into OS and when the shutdown they wouldn't lose all their work. There are some limits but overall a good way to test drive a distro for several days.